# Python 2.7.5 Tkinter Alternate Input Appears Blank

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to make a currency converter that automatically retrieves exchange rates from a JSON file on the internet. I want to design the program so that if it can't access the file, it will let you enter the rate manually. So far everything works except this part. It retrieves data from the JSON file just fine but when you enter it manually, it just appears blank. I'm a complete noob when it comes Python and Tkinter, so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing something simple.

Note: The first part, before the top window, is a copy of the actual code. The window itself is just a mockup to show the problem I'm having.

```
from Tkinter import *

#**Import Bitcoin market data.**
import json
import urllib2

try:
    btcMarketsJSON = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json')
    marketData = json.load(btcMarketsJSON)
    mtGoxUSDdata = [i for i in marketData if i['symbol'] == 'mtgoxUSD']
    bitstampUSDdata = [i for i in marketData if i['symbol'] == 'bitstampUSD']
    mtGoxUSDask = mtGoxUSDdata[0]['ask']
    bitstampUSDask = bitstampUSDdata[0]['ask']
    btcMarketsJSON.close()

except:
    import tkMessageBox as MessageBox
    import tkSimpleDialog as SimpleDialog

    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    if MessageBox.askyesno("Error", "Market data could not be retrieved. Exchange rate will have to be entered manually. Continue anyway?"):
        manualAsk = SimpleDialog.askfloat(" ", "Enter an ask price. This number will be used for all exchanges.")
        mtGoxUSDask = manualAsk
        bitstampUSDask = mtGoxUSDask
    else:
        import sys
        sys.exit()

#**Main Window**      
top = Tk()
top.title("Bitcoin/US Dollar Currency Converter")
top.geometry("+300+300")

selectedAsk = DoubleVar()
selectedAsk.set(mtGoxUSDask)

label = Label(top, textvariable=selectedAsk)
quitButton = Button(top, text="Quit", command=top.destroy)
label.pack()
quitButton.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `root.destroy()` to the end of the `except` clause does the job. As for the reason of such behaviour, I can only guess.

The most likely cause is that, root is still active while we do `selectedAsk = DoubleVar(); selectedAsk.set(mtGoxUSDask)` which is why the `label` does not behave properly.

Comment: That worked! :O And like I suspected, it was something simple. I'd still like to know why it worked though. Maybe the variables were somehow bound to the root window... if that's possible? But then I don't understand how the rest of the program recognized them, but left them blank.

Comment: I am sure that the global variable mtGoxUSDask was not the cause, I verified that. It had something to do with the 2 windows, root & top. The most likely cause is that, root is still active while we do `selectedAsk = DoubleVar(); selectedAsk.set(mtGoxUSDask)` which is why the `label` does not behave properly.